# I'm doing my team members work and am now micromanaged

Tags: work-environment, colleagues

I just started this job 1 month ago and it seems the team leader (who is also in charge of my evaluation) is not liking me not participating in their gossip sessions: talking about employees and guests on a personal level. Making personal phone calls from company phones and sometimes their phones which is not allowed.

They take breaks outside of their allocated time by 30min and sometimes an hour.

I have expressed the issues to our manager and now I am micromanaged by the team leader... and was issued a warning that I have attitude issues...

I believe they hired me to do my work and other team members' work to cut costs. We are 5 and I do about 3 other peoples' work on a daily basis.

The job has good pay and benefits but management is not responding to work issues and I am starting to get anxious going to work.

Should I stick around?

Comment: "I believe they hiried me to do my work and other team memebers work to cut costs." How many team members have been let go because of you so far?

Comment: _"I have expressed the issues to our manager and now i am micromanaged by the team leader... and was issued a warning that i have attitude issues"_ - Sounds like you got punished for swimming against the stream and ratting out your colleagues..

Comment: And, do you have attitude issues? Is that the first time someone told you that?

Comment: If you leave this place, please do all colleagues that still work there or will work there in the future a favor and mention your reasons in your last meeting.

Comment: Never tattletell on your team mates/team leader your first month on the job. That is just career suicide. Yes, you need to move on, and not make this same mistake the next time around. As a brand new employee, you have zero social capital. And yes, your teammates/team leader will make your life a living hell until they get you fired or until you quit. I know it shouldn't be this way, but that's most likely what's going to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd start looking right away as this sounds like a very unprofessional, even toxic workplace environment.

In the meantime, it might be wise to follow up with your manager and relate that things have gotten worse, not improved, since your last talk.  Be totally clear about what is going on and how it was your understanding that having a professional and cooperative work environment is important to you.

Once you have located a suitable replacement position, go for it unless things change for the better both quickly and dramatically.

If I was the manager I'd be very concerned about this team lead's behavior.  Such things are productivity and morale killers and should not be tolerated.

Answer (score 4):

When micro-manager interferes ask "Why?"  The strange thing is that most of these types are hopeless at detail.   An example you gave is 'Attitude problems':  OK what attitudes are those *precisely*?  Insist on proper details for generic epithets such as 'Unprofessional'.  Document your interactions and requests.

Obviously a toxic environment.  Get out as soon as you can.  Don't expend any emotional capital on 'loyalty'.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I stick around?

Anyone that gives you a definitive answer on if you should stay or go, really has no idea what they are talking about.

You need to weigh the negative factors against the positive factors, and potential of both factors in other jobs.

> I am starting to get anxious going to work.

Mental health is important, but so is being able to afford food and shelter.

I suspect you need to get better playing the "political game" at work. Suggestions:

1. Don't participate in gossip sessions (you don't have any right to to begin with)
2. Ignore minor rule-breaking by your supervisor
3. Improve your attitude in whatever way it is sought
4. Do the best you can

Comment: I dont have issues with them taking breaks but for example when the supervisor is on the phone (which is not allowed) he wouldnt even call me by my name when he needs something which forces me to be either attentive to his whole convsrsation or risk performance penalties....

Comment: I have offered a solution to my supervisor to atleast call me by my name if you need me but he gets all defensive and irritated...I am very new to coorporate politics indeed. Its more like highschool all over again....

Answer (score 0):

You may not be a best fit for this position, unless you want to be a beast of burden for your team while not being particularly liked.
You may have your reasons (money / benefits etc), but mental state is also very important.

IMHO, toxic work environments should be left as soon as you get the chance.

Look for a new place and leave when you get desired salary / benefits / work.

Comment: i hope i cam survive this. 4 people gossip at ear distance where you are not allowed to leave or have more space. thanks anyways

Comment: @workstuff As experience states, you cant.  These situations escalate, how fast is individual timeline, but usually fast